# Round up or round down an input from float to int in Python

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way to round up (if the decimal is 5 or higher) and round down (if the decimal is 4 or lower) an input in python.

To make it more clear as an example.

Ask for an user input:

```
user_input = input("Please input a number: ")
```

Then the program should check if the the input is f.e 2.5 (in this case round up to 3) or 2.4 (in this case round down to 2).

How do I make this work? I wanted to make it work with it but I don't know how.

Example:

```
user_input = input("Please input a number: ")

if user_input > 5:
    roundup
```

Something like this I think you know what I mean by now.

Comment: Add 0.5 and then simply round down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up:

```
import math
print(math.ceil(4.2))
```

Down:

```
import math
print(math.floor(4.2))
```

Comment: This is a really nice answer I looked for this, but how can I check the decimals of an input float? I wanted to check for example if the decimal of the input is higher than 5 use math.ceil, if it's 4 or lower use math.floor. You get my idea? I want to do it like this if user_input second decimal > 5 and then use math.ceil(user_input) else math.floor(user_input)

Comment: @MarekSczokowzky abs(math.floor(4.2)-4.2)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this (using `round()` with validation):

```
while True:
    try:
      user_input = round(float(input("Please input a number: ")))
      break
    except ValueError:
      print("Enter a number please")

print(user_input)
```

Later do something with `user_input`